# View images stopped displaying

Tags: views

I created a view that displays a content types images in a Jcarousel. When I first created the view with the images it was working. I then removed the images to eventually upload new images. When I did, the views stopped working. You would only see an empty white box where the thumbnail image WOULD have been. It scrolls and all just no image. Have the same problem with another view I created using the product images as well. I tried clearing the cache but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Im guessing when you uploaded some images they, or a the setting in your view have a different 'image_style' associated with them.

Comment: Did you override your view?

Comment: No, the view is being called in block.